# Unable To Use PC Partitions Upon First Installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

got an available laptop to setup HP-EliteBook 840 G1. I'm using my Kubuntu w/o any issues and etc. Not too advanced user but manage all I need via the embedded interface of Ubuntu. I've decided I'm going to run this laptop with Grub to load Win7 Prof. and Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. So far so good. I've installed my Windows, made the partitions leaving 100GB - Win / 75 GB Linux and ~300GB for storage. Windows started fine, I've formatted the partitions under Windows as NTFS, named them and etc.

Next step - I started with 64Bit Version of Ubuntu, downloaded the latest LTS version and made bootable USB Stick. However when I start the installation Ubuntu runs O.K. I went trough the main changes (I haven't used Ubutu for a while, but Kubuntu is almost the same apart of the appearance), when I start the actual installation though I've been shocked I don't have HDD listed (see screen 1). It gives an error I'm unable to understand (suspect it was something related to the HDD Properties and how I installed the Windows on a first place - I'm running on SATA - AHCI - see screens 2&3)

Surprisingly enough (screen 4) I'm seeing the partitions just fine through the Partition Manager under Ubuntu. I also see them when I run my Windows... When I tried to find more about this issue I've run across few documented cases where people explain it depends on how you've installed your Windows... and for some reason Windows wipe out some of the drivers as unnecessary for it... which can cause such issue. I'm absolutely fine to start from scratch (re-imaging my Windows and my Ubuntu) but would appreciate if someone can explain to me what I did wrong and how to get this fixed next time? Also do you know what could be the primary cause for this problem and can I sort it out now w/o installing everything again?

I had to remove screen 1 and 2. 1 was the partition manager on first install - no partitions and / or unalocated space. And screen 2 was simply crash notice.

[image]

[image]

Appreciate your view on this,
Hangman13us

Comment: Can you boot the installation media and at the initial sort-of-text-mode screen press F6 and select `nodmraid`? See bugs [1062625](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1062625) and [1064151](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1064151).

Comment: It is either me doing something wrong or I'm not having this option. Couldn't find this "nodmraid" but the bugs seems what I'm experiencing at the moment...

Comment: When you boot the installation media the very first screen is sort of purplish mostly empty with a mystic hieroglyph at the bottom (which should represent a keyboard, an equals sign and a human, meaning press any key for internationalization). It lasts only a few seconds. Press the space key at this screen. A list of languages will appear. Press Enter to select English. A purplish screen will appear with a menu; at this screen press F6 and choose `nodmraid`.

Comment: I don't have access to this. I'm using 16.04 Ubuntu USB stick I made myself, but when I give direct install it loads the graphic environment and I start with Language selection, pressing F1 to F12 doesn't do anything on this machine, I remember this logo you're referring to from my Kubuntu 14.XX installation in the past...

Comment: Exploring the options there - when I press I can use "enter" to select the option, "e" to edit the menu, and "c" for command line - is there I run this as command? I don't actually have any outcome if I press F6 during the first menu...

Comment: You don't give direct install. I have checked with a USB flash drive made with Rufus. The computer boots from the USB flash drive, a mostly empty dark purple screen appears, press space, a full-screen list of languages appears, press Enter, a menu appears with items "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu", "Check disk for defects" etc. and a list of special keys on the last line of the screen (F1 Help, F2 Language, ..., F6 Other). Here you press F6, select nodmraid and press Enter (places an x near it),  press Esc to close the submenu, select Try Ubuntu from main menu.

Comment: I tried but it allows me access to these options only if I use previous version of Ubuntu - I tried with 12.04.4 LTS. When I give the nodmraid option it starts giving me an error with exit code 10 from the boot manager, if I ignore it it shows no space available and asks me install in the USB itself. Really odd. I wonder if I should change something in the BIOS.